# Reverse gear in Auto transmission not properly engaging after pushing car

Tags: automatic-transmission, audi, a4

I have a 1997 Audi A4 quattro that was not driven for a while, It was given to me by a friend who emigrated. All gears were working fine however the battery was flat and the car was parked right up to the wall so i had to push it back to be able to jump start it.

I was not sure the best way to push it without damage so slipped the car into R and pushed car back a couple of hundred yrds or so which then allowed me to bring my other car up and give the car and connect up some jumper cables and start the car.
Everything works fine except now when i select reverse the car nothing happens unless i give the car a nudge or it rolls backwards, then it will jolt in to gear and reverse fine.  Does anyone know how this could be fixed at all please?
thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the transmission fluid to ensure it is up to level? If it is up to level, I'm wondering if the reverse band has decided to no longer actuate correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the fluid is ok, and all other gears work fine, i will research the band thank you

Comment: There's two parts to the reverse band: the band itself and a servo. Could be the band, but more than likely the servo or electronics controlling the servo. Really, you probably need to take it to a transmission shop to get it fixed. Also, I doubt your pushing it, even a couple hundred yards, would have had any effect on it.